# How do I join various images next to each other in OS X?

Tags: macos, images, automator

I would like to join various PNG images horizontally in Mac, either using the console or Automator. Is this possible? How?

An example:

Given these two images:

[image]

[image]

The result would be:

[image]

The images have the same size but their size is not constrained. The number of images is between 2 and a few dozen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)'s `append` to combine multiple images together. `+append` for horizontal, `-append` for vertical.

`convert mrdUM.png 477kv.png +append appended.png`

[image]

`convert mrdUM.png 477kv.png -append vertical.png`

[image]

[Reference](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append)

---

To install ImageMagick, I suggest either using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php) or [Homebrew](https://mxcl.dev/homebrew/). After installing either one, it's as simple as

`port install imagemagick`

`brew install imagemagick`

Comment: It would be great to include a short explanation of how to install ImageMagick on a Mac.

Comment: `brew install imagemagick` ended up with `error couldn't connect to host` for imagemagick dependency: `pkg-config`. I ended up searching for an old version named "ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin10" that runs on 10.6.8. An `export MAGICK_HOME="$HOME/ImageMagick-6.6.7"` an `export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH"` and an `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"` to install ImageMagick on Snow Leopard. That finally successfully made the `convert` command concatenate the jpeg files.